# What FreeBSD should I install if I use Intel Pentium 4

Tags: freebsd

I have [Pentium 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4) and I want to install [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/where.html) with [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/). What distribution should I download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be i386. You can use disc1 or dvd1, depending on preference. Read the documentation for details.

Comment: P4 has full support for amd64 so if machine has more than 4GB RAM amd64 is mandatory

Comment: Or PAE. (see pae(4))

Comment: PAE is a source of hardly diagnosted faults and should be avoided if possible. Amd64 version of FreeBSD fully compatible with all x86 software and there is no reasons to prefer x86 even if there is less than 4GB RAM on the host.